# How to improve the efficiency of an algorithm that does multiple fetch calls in terms of security and complexity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

The exercise is Write a JavaScript package that is able to:

1. fetch an array of URLs which contain JSON data
2. return their contents in a promise

I have already made a solution to this exercise, but I would like some input on how to improve this solution in terms of efficiency, security and complexity. I have also included unit tests for this solution.

**index.js**

```
const { InvalidParameterError, EmptyArrayError, InvalidURLError, FetchError, APIError } = require("./errors");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const validUrl = require('valid-url');

const links = [
    'https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ftse-fsi.json', 
    'https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gbp-hkd.json', 
    'https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gbp-usd.json'
]

/** 
 * iterates through the array and fetches data from each url, includes edge cases
 * @params {urls} array of URLs
 * @return {Promise} promise which is an array of the data fetched from the URL in JSON format

 */
function requestMultipleUrls (urls) {
    if (!Array.isArray(urls)){
        console.log('Parameter passed is not in array format', urls)
        return new InvalidParameterError('urls should be inside in an array')
    }

    if (urls.length === 0) {
        console.log('Array cannot be empty', urls)
        return new EmptyArrayError('Array of urls cannot be empty')
    }

    const promises =  urls.map(async (url) => {
        if ((!validUrl.isUri(url))) {
            console.log('URL is in incorrect format', url)
            return new InvalidURLError('Input URL is not in the correct format')
        }

        try {
            const data = await fetch(url);
            const { status } = data
            
            if (status !== 200) {
                console.log(`Your fetch call returned a status code of ${status}, check if the URL you entered is correct`)
                return new APIError('Something went wrong with the URL you are trying to fetch', status)
            } else {
                return mapData(data)
            }
            
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
            return new FetchError('Something went wrong during the fetch call')
        }
    })

    return Promise.all(promises)
}


/** 
 * Deconstructs the data being passed to form an object that is eventually returned
 * @params {data} response that is recieved from the fetch call in requestMultipleUrls
 * @return {final} object that is formatted
 */
const mapData = async (data) => {
    const {url, status} = data
    const final =  {
        url,
        status,
        body: await data.json()
    }
    return final
}

requestMultipleUrls(links).then((data) => console.log(data))

module.exports = {
    requestMultipleUrls
}
```

**errors.js**

```
class InvalidParameterError {
    constructor (message) {
        this.status = 400;
        this.message = message;
    }
}

class EmptyArrayError {
    constructor(message) {
        this.status = 400;
        this.message = message;
    }
}

class InvalidURLError {
    constructor(message) {
        this.status = 400;
        this.message = message
    }
}

class APIError {
    constructor(message, status){
        this.status = status,
        this.message = message
    }
}

class FetchError {
    constructor(message) {
        this.status = 502;
        ths.message = message
    }
}

module.exports = {
    InvalidParameterError,
    EmptyArrayError,
    InvalidURLError,
    FetchError,
    APIError
}
```

**index.spec.js**

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { requestMultipleUrls } = require('../index');
const gbpUsd = require('./gbp-usd.json');
const gbpHkd = require('./gbp-hkd.json')

describe('requestMultipleUrl intended functionality', () => {
    it('function should return an accumulated API response', async () => {
    const dummyUrls = [
            'https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gbp-usd.json',
            'https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gbp-hkd.json'
    ]
    const promise = await requestMultipleUrls(dummyUrls);
    expect(promise).to.deep.equal([gbpUsd, gbpHkd]);
    }) 
})

describe('requestMultipleUrl edge cases', () => {
    it('should throw an error if the urls in the array do not match URI standards', async () => {
        const dummyUrls = [
            'lfkjklwfklm',
            'ekefjkf;lfl;'
        ]

        try {
            await requestMultipleUrls(dummyUrls)
        } catch (error) {
            expect(error.message).to.eql('Input URL is not in the correct format')
        }
    })

    it('should throw an error if URL array is empty', async () => {
        const dummyUrls = []
        try {
            await requestMultipleUrls(dummyUrls)
        } catch (error) {
            expect(error.message).to.eql('Array of urls cannot be empty')
        }
    })

    it('should throw an error if the parameter being passed is not an array', async () => {
        const dummyUrls = 'https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gbp-hkd.json'
        try {
            await requestMultipleUrls(dummyUrls)
        } catch (error) {
            expect(error.message).to.eql('urls should be inside in an array')
        }
    })

    it('should throw an error if status code is not 200', async () => {
        const dummyUrls = ['https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gbp-jpy.json']
        try {
            await requestMultipleUrls(dummyUrls)
        } catch(error){
            expect(error.message).to.eql('Something went wrong with the URL you are trying to fetch')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: If this is working code and you want code improvement suggestions, you can post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.  Please read their posting guidelines and follow them.

Comment: A problem I see here is that the caller of `requestMultipleUrls()` will get a promise that resolves to an array.  Each element in the array will either contain some data or an Error object so the caller has to check the type of every element in the array to see if there was an error for that URL.  Is that how you want this function to be used?  Instead of rejecting the promise when there's an error?

Comment: Security isn’t really a concern here. You’re just fetching data from a server. But you’re kind of doing some unexpected things by not throwing real errors on errors. When I’m using a promise, I expect errors to go to the error handler. Also you’re obscuring the errors the server sent you. Which is non standard. Also, generally unit tests don’t actually make a request to any server. They should be standalone.